# Array is not getting updating after response come

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6

I have predefined array of objects which I am going to update by performing some operations. I am displaying array on angular material modal for that I am using **Material dialog**

I am passing my array of objects via data property of openDialogue(). It is displaying properly. But when I try to editing on it and reopen that modal, that modal is not showing updated data. To see updated data I have to reload the page.

Below is my code:

**Predefined array file - workMethod.ts:**

```
export const workMethod: any[] = [
    {
        text: 'Individual',
        price: '',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Group',
        price: '',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Couples',
        price: '',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Family',
        price: '',
        checked: false
    },
    {
        text: 'Online sessions',
        price: '',
        checked: false
    }
]
```

**ts file on which modal is opening:**

```
import { workMethod } from '../../../shared/workMethod';

ngOnInit() {
    this.userservice.makeAPICall(this.userservice.postMethod, 
      this.userservice.gettherapistprofile, data, (response) => {
     // this is the api call where values from database is coming..

     this.therapistdetails = response.data;

     if(this.therapistdetails.workMethod && 
         this.therapistdetails.workMethod.length) {
        this.therapistdetails.workMethod.forEach((method) => {
          workMethod.forEach((type) => {
            if(type.text == method.workMethodType && method.checked) {
              type.checked = true;
              type.price = method.setPrice;
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
}

// this is the function by which on click it will open modal
  addWorkMethodModal() {
    let workMethodData = {
      title: 'Work Method',
      data: workMethod
    }
    // console.log('work method... ', workMethodData);
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: workMethodData,
    })

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // console.log('after closed value... ', result);
      if (result && result.action && result.action == 'workMethod') {
        if(result.workMethod && result.workMethod.length) {
          result.workMethod.forEach(element => {
            element['workMethodType'] = element['checked'];
            element['checked'] = element['selected'];
            element['setPrice'] = element['price'];

            delete element['price'];
            delete element['selected'];
          });
        }
        let data = {
          userID: this.id,
          workMethod: result.workMethod
        }
        this.userservice.makeAPICall(this.userservice.postMethod, this.userservice.updateWorkMethod, data, (response) => {
          console.log('response... ', response);
          this.therapistdetails.workMethod = response.data;
          this.dataToPush.next(response.data);
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

**template file:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
  *ngFor="let workmethod of therapistdetails.workMethod; let i=index">
     <div *ngIf="workmethod" class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
             <p *ngIf="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].checked == true"> 
               <mat-checkbox [checked]="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].checked"></mat-checkbox>
             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <p class="master" *ngIf="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].checked == true">
             <mat-form-field                                           
               floatPlaceholder="never" 
               class="margin-top-25px example-full-width">
             <input                                                          
              matInput                                  
              class="input"                                         
            [(ngModel)]="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].workMethodType"                                                               
              placeholder="Answer text" >
            </mat-form-field>
           </p>       
         </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" 
     *ngIf="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].checked == true">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width margin-top-25px">
           <input                                                
             type="number"
             class="input-price"                                                   
             [(ngModel)]="workmethod.setPrice" 
             matInput >
           </mat-form-field>                                             
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
           <span class="currency" 
       *ngIf="therapistdetails.workMethod[i].checked == true">
           {{ therapistdetails.currency}}
           </span>        
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <p class="Addmore pointer" (click)="addWorkMethodModal()">Add 
          More</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**this is the modal ts file:**

```
orderForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;


ngOnInit() {
    if(this.data.data && this.data.data.length) {
      console.log('data from component: ', this.data.data);
      this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        items: this.formBuilder.array([ ])
      })

      this.setCheckBoxValue();
    }
    this.blankForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      blankItems: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
  }

  setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
      this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
        this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          checked: element.text,
          selected: element.checked,
          price: element.price
        }))
      })
  }

onCloseCancel() {
    this.ref.close('cancel');
  }
```

**modal html file:**

```
<div *ngIf="data.data.length" [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls;let i=index">
        <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="selected" name="selected" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.selected.value" >
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <mat-form-field 
            floatPlaceholder="never" class="margin-top-25px example-full-width" >
                <input 
                matInput
                class="input" name="checked"
                formControlName="checked"
                value="{{item.controls.checked.value}}"
                placeholder="{{data.title}}"
                >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" *ngIf="data.title == 'Work Method'">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width margin-top-25px">
              <input 
              type="number"
              class="input-price"
              formControlName="price"
              value="{{item.controls.price.value}}"
              matInput >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

At the initial page load it is working properly. But when I do change in modal and reopen it, changed value not showing up. Please help me out.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz for your code

Comment: @Sasi, I am trying to create but nothing is happening.. only loader is loading. Is it not possible for you to check it without it?

Comment: Okay.. I tried on stackblitz.. Hope you may get idea. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The issue was occurring because the data returned by modal dialog was not having the same structure as your original data. Your output data is having the structure like this:

```
checked: element.text,
selected: element.checked,
price: element.price
```

While your source structure is:

```
text: 'Individual',
price: '',
checked: false
```

You should set up your `setCheckBoxValue` method like this:

```
setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    if(this.data.title == 'Work Method') {
      this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
        this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          checked: element.text,
          selected: element.checked,
          price: element.price
        }))
      })
    }
    else {
      this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
        this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          checked: element.text,
          selected: element.checked,
        }))
      });
    }
  }
```

Similarly, change your template like this:

```
<div>
  <h2 mat-dialog-title> {{data.title}} </h2>
  <hr>

  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div *ngIf="data.data.length" [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls;let i=index">
        <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked" name="selected" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.checked.value" >
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <mat-form-field 
            floatPlaceholder="never" class="margin-top-25px example-full-width" >
                <input 
                matInput
                class="input" name="checked"
                formControlName="text"
                value="{{item.controls.text.value}}"               
                >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" *ngIf="data.title == 'Work Method'">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width margin-top-25px">
              <input 
              type="number"
              class="input-price"
              formControlName="price"
              value="{{item.controls.price.value}}"
              matInput >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>

  <div>
    <hr>
    <mat-dialog-actions style="float: right">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCloseCancel()" class="btn-style-cancell">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCloseConfirm()"
       class="btn-style">Confirm</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-array-h9kqmw?file=src/styles.css

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @user2216584, your and Stas answer almost similar. And its worked for me.. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you need to use emit by close the modal window

something like:

```
onClose(e) {
    this.dialogRef.close(e)
}
```

P.S.: the data that you send from the component and that you send to the component must be the same. try to send the form and keep track of what you push in form in a modal window

Comment: in this line you will get new data in result. `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {}` then after next open modal you need send new data and push it to your fb=)

Comment: here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: the data that you send from the component and that you send to the component must be the same. try to send the form. something like `this.thisDialogRef.close(this.orderForm.value)` and keep track of what you push in form in a modal window

Comment: I made the data same at both side and assign response to the **workMethod array**. And it is working properly.. Thank you @Stas..